# Can anyone explain scopes in reactive charms to me please (juju 2.0)?

Tags: juju, interface

I'm having some difficulty with scopes in juju 2.0 (2.0-rc1-0ubuntu1~1) and the [documentation](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/developer-layers-interfaces) doesn't go into much detail.

I've written an interface at https://github.com/autonomouse/interface-weebl using the global scope (or so I thought).

I've got 2 charms and have set the interface in the appropriate provides/requires as "oildashboard".

One charm is called "weebl" and a second mock charm that I'm using for testing called "anti-weebl". Anti-weebl doesn't do much except to display the a piece of info passed to it in it's juju status message, like this:

```
@when('oildashboard.available')
def display_data_in_status(oildashboard):
    hookenv.status_set('active', oildashboard.weebl_username())
```

It seemed to be working yesterday, happily dispaying data in the juju status, but now that I have involved a second relation to a third charm from weebl, I get `ValueError: Conversation with scope 'anti-weebl' not found`.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong wrt global scopes please?

This is the full error (after I removed the `unit-weebl-1: 14:54:29 INFO unit.weebl/1.oildashboard-relation-joined` from the beginning of every line):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-weebl-1/charm/hooks/oildashboard-relation-joined", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/__init__.py", line 78, in main
    bus.dispatch()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 434, in dispatch
    _invoke(other_handlers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 417, in _invoke
    handler.invoke()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/bus.py", line 291, in invoke
    self._action(*args)
  File "/var/lib/juju/agents/unit-weebl-1/charm/reactive/weebl.py", line 52, in request_db
    pgsql.set_remote('extensions', 'tablefunc')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/relations.py", line 323, in set_remote
    self.conversation(scope).set_remote(key, value, data, **kwdata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/charms/reactive/relations.py", line 263, in conversation
    raise ValueError("Conversation with scope '%s' not found" % scope)
ValueError: Conversation with scope 'anti-weebl' not found
unit-weebl-1: 14:54:29 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation hook "oildashboard-relation-joined" failed: exit status 1
unit-weebl-1: 14:54:29 INFO juju.worker.uniter awaiting error resolution for "relation-joined" hook
```

Answer (score 1):

After asking around a bit, it turns out that it has nothing to do with scopes! It was actually because we were using `set_remote(...)` elsewhere in the charm, which is not supposed to be used outside of the interface layer.